# iOS Implementing a Messaging System

Tags: ios, chat, messaging

I'm currently making an iOS app and I want to include a messaging system similar to the standard iOS one.

I've done a google search and think [UIBubbleTableView](http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/) is probably the best view to for the front end. However, I'm struggling to find a good way to handle the backend. I'm using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) as a database.

Would I have a table for the messages, and then have a sender & receiver ID in each row? Or have a table for each individual communication between users? Either way seems a bit like a stupid way of doing it, as you're either going to be searching a huge database for the correct messages, or have loads of tables..

I found [this](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com), however it isn't really what I want, as it's not showing communication between users, rather in a chat room.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a communication protocol. Take a look at XMPP (Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol) which is XML based, open source and used widely for many well known messengers like Google Talk or Jabber. There are many open source libraries which you may use in your application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP

About hosting your own server somewhere: It is not necessary. You may use Google's Google Talk servers or the ones from Jabber.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have a look into that. I found [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/) which should help. Had a quick glance over and do I need to host a server on my own computer for it to work? I can't seem to find any services that host a xmpp server online..